# adding a resource file manually in Dev-Cpp

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, makefile, resources

I am making a simple Win32 C++ game and when I made a header file and a resource file once I compiled it I had an error message from the compile log wich said "*** missing separator. stop"and it was from the make file in the line that had my new resource file.

This is not the first time I try to make a resource file as I did it with another simple apps and it worked fine but now with this application it didnt work also I checked the makefile from another aplication and they had the same syntax.

Any help would be appreciated.
And by the way im using Dev-Cpp ide and compiler if that may help you find a solution for my problem.

**Edit:**The makefile code is:

```
# Project: Win32 Game 1
# Makefile created by Dev-C++ 4.9.9.2

CPP  = g++.exe -D__DEBUG__
CC   = gcc.exe -D__DEBUG__
WINDRES = windres.exe
RES  = Win32_Game_#1_private.res
OBJ  = WinMain.o $(RES)
LINKOBJ  = WinMain.o $(RES)
LIBS =  -L"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib" -mwindows  -lgmon -pg  -g3 
INCS =  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include" 
CXXINCS =  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2/include"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2"  -I"C:/Dev-Cpp/include" 
BIN  = "Win32 Game 1.exe"
CXXFLAGS = $(CXXINCS)   -pg -g3
CFLAGS = $(INCS)   -pg -g3
RM = rm -f

.PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

all: all-before "Win32 Game 1.exe" all-after


clean: clean-custom
${RM} $(OBJ) $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CPP) $(LINKOBJ) -o "Win32 Game 1.exe" $(LIBS)

WinMain.o: WinMain.cpp
    $(CPP) -c WinMain.cpp -o WinMain.o $(CXXFLAGS)

Win32_Game_#1_private.res: Win32_Game_#1_private.rc Settings.rc 
    $(WINDRES) -i Win32_Game_#1_private.rc --input-format=rc -o     Win32_Game_#1_private.res -O coff
```

Settings.rc is the resource file that im trying to add

Comment: You have an error in your Makefile, if you want to know more you'll need to post it.

Comment: @user657267 ok i had just posted it as an edit to the question you can see it and give me your opinion and by the way it is auto generated by Dev-Cpp not by me

Comment: The `#` in the filename is being interpreted as a comment. You'll have to rename the file and report that as a bug to the maintainers of whatever fork of Dev-C++ you're using.

Comment: ok but it tells me build error in line 32 witch is where the resource files are being called and it says *** missing separator. stop

Comment: @andlabs I guess I solved the problem when i made a new project and added the source code to it and every thing is going well now.